# Assign css class to php code for a shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a lot of posts which have a particular shortcode like [rest massage=""][/rest] and a text in between, and also the text is unique that mean in all the site its not used, only in this shortcode. the shortcode doesn't have any class or id assigned. now I want to assign a css class to it so that i can design it. how can i do it with php or jquery.
I founded this in the shortcode.php

```
function rcp_restrict_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'userlevel'    => 'none',
    'message'      => '',
    'paid'         => false,
    'level'        => 0,
    'subscription' => ''
), $atts, 'restrict' );

global $rcp_options, $user_ID;

if ( strlen( $atts['message'] ) > 0 ) {
    $teaser = $atts['message'];
} else {
    $teaser = rcp_get_restricted_content_message( ! empty( $atts['paid'] ) );
}

$subscriptions = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['subscription'] ) );

$has_access = false;
$classes    = 'rcp_restricted';

$customer  = rcp_get_customer(); // currently logged in customer
$is_active = rcp_user_has_active_membership();
$has_access_level = rcp_user_has_access( get_current_user_id(), $atts['level'] );

if( $atts['paid'] ) {

    if ( rcp_user_has_paid_membership() && $has_access_level ) {
        $has_access = true;
    }

    $classes = 'rcp_restricted rcp_paid_only';

} elseif ( $has_access_level ) {

    $has_access = true;
}

if ( ! empty( $subscriptions ) && ! empty( $subscriptions[0] ) ) {
    if ( $is_active && ! empty( $customer ) && count( array_intersect( rcp_get_customer_membership_level_ids( $customer->get_id() ), $subscriptions ) ) ) {
        $has_access = true;
    } else {
        $has_access = false;
    }
}

if ( $atts['userlevel'] === 'none' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $has_access = false;
}
if( 'none' != $atts['userlevel'] ) {
    $roles = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['userlevel'] ) );

    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        if ( current_user_can( strtolower( $role ) ) ) {
            $has_access = true;
            break;
        } else {
            $has_access = false;
        }
    }
}
```

plz help.

Comment: As far as I see from the shortcode's code, it doesn't generate any HTML. It just seems to set the `$has_access` variable `true` or `false`.

Comment: i just want to asign a class to [restrtict] shortcode. it cant be done? any way

Comment: What is your shortcode returning? I see nothing the shortcode is returning that you could add a class to?

Comment: I dont now much php. This is the link of the php file, plzz see if u can help me, becz the only way for me to style the text in the [restrict] shortcode is to edit one by one all 800 post and that would be a nightmare for me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bVV04h52sdQjpoGKUXDM9q4kHLKSXNeF/view?usp=sharing